# LSTM Autoencoders - architecture

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoders, feature-engineering

I am a bit confused about the structure of LSTM autoencoders, as far as I know, common way to construct vanilla autoencoders is bottleneck structure, for instance, start with 40 nodes, encode it to 30 then decode it back to 40. When I checked LSTM autoencoders implementations, I saw people are using structures like starting from 40 nodes encode it to 100 nodes to 20 nodes and decode it back to 100 nodes and 40 nodes. Is there specific reason for this construction, if there is can someone explain me the reason?

Ps: My aim with autoencoders is to reduce the dimension of time series data

Thank you so much

Comment: Are “nodes” the entire feature set of the input sequence? Or do you really mean “time steps,” in which case each turn step would have many features

Comment: Entire feature set, so lets say I have 40 features and I am using 20 time steps in this case my input shape is [Batch size, time steps, features]. The part I did not understand is number of nodes in the layers. What I generally saw in vanilla autoencoders is 40-20-40 neurons but in LSTM what I saw is like 40-100-20-100-40,  instead of reducing dimensions gradually, first they increase it then reduce it

Comment: Can you provide a source on one of these autoencoders?

Comment: If you want to reduce the dimension why do you increase the size of the middle layers?

Comment: @AlexR. sure, Alex, https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/17_autoencoders_and_gans.ipynb here is the second version of Geron's book also this the tutorial from ML mastery: https://machinelearningmastery.com/lstm-autoencoders/

Comment: Thats exactly my question @LernerZhang in tutorials I followed they first increase than decrease, which I did not understand. In the end, I achieved better results with vanilla autoencoders rather than LSTM autoencoders.